# Can I disable the auto-publishing in google appstore after uploading

Tags: android

I plan to upload my APK file to google appstore, and am wondering if I can use
any scheduled publishing after the publishing is done, because this new version 
is published, I must apply to my server corresponding to new APK.

As far as I know, I did it in Apple appstore.

Thank you.

Comment: Your server needs to support both old and new versions of your APK file. You cannot force users to install updates to your app at any particular point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your APK for Beta or Alpha testing, it will still be published but not publicly until you decide to do so.